# I need same label to repeat 3 times in bar chart tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        ymin=0,
        width  = 12cm,
        height = 5cm,
        bar width=20pt,
        ylabel={number of participants},
        nodes near coords,
 %      nodes near coords align=below, % places labels inside bars
        symbolic x coords={wells,leemput,wang, proposed,wells,leemput,wang, proposed,wells,leemput,wang, proposed},
        xtick = data,
        enlarge y limits={value=0.2,upper},
        legend pos=north west
    ]
    \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates {(wells, 1) (leemput, 2) (wang, 3) (proposed, 4) (wells, 4)(leemput, 2) (wang, 3) (proposed, 4)(wells, 4)(leemput, 2) (wang, 3) (proposed, 4)};
     \addplot[fill=red] coordinates {(wells, 3) (leemput, 2) (wang, 8) (proposed, 4)(wells, 4)(leemput, 2) (wang, 3) (proposed, 4)(wells, 4)(leemput, 2) (wang, 3) (proposed, 4)};
      \legend{1\%, 5\%)
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I think this question is similar or equal to [tikz overlapping bars](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/190942/43317)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use a table for your data it is possible to load the xticklabels from this table:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.dat}
wells 1 3
leemput 2 2
wang 3 8
proposed 4 4
wells 4 4
leemput 2 2
wang 3 3
proposed 4 4
wells 4 4
leemput 2 2
wang 3 3
proposed 4 4
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        ymin=0,
        width  = 12cm,
        height = 5cm,
        bar width=5pt,
        ylabel={number of participants},
        nodes near coords,
        xticklabel style={rotate=90},
        xtick = data,
        table/header=false,
        xticklabels from table={mydata.dat}{[index]0},
        enlarge y limits={value=0.2,upper},
        legend pos=north west
    ]
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=1]{mydata.dat};
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=2]{mydata.dat};
    \legend{1\%, 5\%}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can use inline tables

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        ymin=0,
        width  = 12cm,
        height = 5cm,
        bar width=5pt,
        ylabel={number of participants},
        nodes near coords,
        xticklabel style={rotate=90},
        xtick = data,
        table/header=false,
        table/row sep=\\,
        xticklabels from table={
          wells\\lemput\\wang\\proposed\\
          wells\\lemput\\wang\\proposed\\
          wells\\lemput\\wang\\proposed\\
          }{[index]0},
        enlarge y limits={value=0.2,upper},
        legend pos=north west
    ]
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{1\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\};
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{3\\2\\8\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.