# tikz ovelapping bars

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

The following code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn, openright]{report}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        ymin=0,
        width  = 12cm,
        height = 5cm,
        bar width=5pt,
        ylabel={number of participants},
        nodes near coords,
        symbolic x coords={wells,leemput,wang, proposed,wells,leemput,wang, proposed,wells,leemput,wang, proposed},
        xtick = data,
        enlarge y limits={value=0.2,upper},
        legend pos=north west
    ]
    \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates {(wells, 1) (leemput, 2) (wang, 3) (proposed, 4) (wells, 4)(leemput, 2) (wang, 3) (proposed, 4)(wells, 4)(leemput, 2) (wang, 3) (proposed, 4)};
    \addplot[fill=red] coordinates {(wells, 3) (leemput, 2) (wang, 8) (proposed, 4)(wells, 4)(leemput, 2) (wang, 3) (proposed, 4)(wells, 4)(leemput, 2) (wang, 3) (proposed, 4)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{JS of GM}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: I formatted the code in your question and up-loaded an image of the result; I hope it's OK. Could you please add a brief description of the problem?

Comment: There is more space for the labels if you make the bars wider `bar width=15pt` and the diagram a little higher `height = 6cm`

Comment: I think the question also needs a ... question

Comment: They overlap because you are adding more than one bar at the same point (per plot)... e.g. `\addplot[blue] coordinates {(wells, 1), ..., (wells, 4),...};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** taking into account the desire (braces below) of the comment

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        ymin=0,
        width  = 12cm,
        height = 5cm,
        bar width=5pt,
        ylabel={number of participants},
        nodes near coords,
        xticklabel style={rotate=90},
        xtick = data,
        table/header=false,
        table/row sep=\\,
        xticklabels from table={
          wells\\lemput\\wang\\proposed\\
          wells\\lemput\\wang\\proposed\\
          wells\\lemput\\wang\\proposed\\
          }{[index]0},
        enlarge y limits={value=0.2,upper},
        legend pos=north west
    ]
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{1\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\};
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{3\\2\\8\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\};
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,3,4,7,8,11}{\coordinate(l#1)at(axis cs:#1,0);}
    \end{axis}
    \coordinate(bbs)at(current bounding box.south);
    \foreach[count=\i,evaluate={\s=int(4*\i-1)},evaluate={\e=int(4*(\i-1)}] \text in {Text 1,Text 2,Text 3} 
      \draw[decorate,decoration=brace]([xshift=8pt]l\s|-bbs)--node[below=5pt]{\text}([xshift=-8pt]l\e|-bbs);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Original answer**

Because of

> `symbolic x coords={wells,leemput,wang,proposed,wells,leemput,wang,proposed, wells,leemput,wang, proposed},`

I think you are looking for something like that

[image]

Loading the xtick labels from a table and using the `\coordindex` as x is one possibility to get the above picture.

You can use either inline tables for the xtick labels and the y values

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        ymin=0,
        width  = 12cm,
        height = 5cm,
        bar width=5pt,
        ylabel={number of participants},
        nodes near coords,
        xticklabel style={rotate=90},
        xtick = data,
        table/header=false,
        table/row sep=\\,
        xticklabels from table={
          wells\\lemput\\wang\\proposed\\
          wells\\lemput\\wang\\proposed\\
          wells\\lemput\\wang\\proposed\\
          }{[index]0},
        enlarge y limits={value=0.2,upper},
        legend pos=north west
    ]
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{1\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\};
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]{3\\2\\8\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\4\\2\\3\\4\\};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or an external table containing both the xtick labels and the y values

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.dat}
wells 1 3
leemput 2 2
wang 3 8
proposed 4 4
wells 4 4
leemput 2 2
wang 3 3
proposed 4 4
wells 4 4
leemput 2 2
wang 3 3
proposed 4 4
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        ymin=0,
        width  = 12cm,
        height = 5cm,
        bar width=5pt,
        ylabel={number of participants},
        nodes near coords,
        xticklabel style={rotate=90},
        xtick = data,
        table/header=false,
        xticklabels from table={mydata.dat}{[index]0},
        enlarge y limits={value=0.2,upper},
        legend pos=north west
    ]
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=1]{mydata.dat};
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=2]{mydata.dat};
    \legend{1\%, 5\%}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For every four i need an under braces with Text below it. can you help me with this..

Comment: See my supplemented answer.

Comment: I need two of these bar charts side by side in  a row  in my journal. could that happen?